# Is there a word or concise phrase meaning to set aside many tasks or a surplus of work for another?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

For a very long time I had a misunderstanding and thought the word expressing this was "sandbagging" which is very much an incorrect use.

Is there a phrase I can use when I am saying that I am stacking up things to do for one of my juniors at work, so that they will have plenty to do and not run out of work? The idea is to have a plentiful amount of work available and set up. think: "task-stockpiling" I have searched quite a bit to no avail. It's one of those things where I swear there was a word for this and it's escaping me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's wrong with **stockpile** itself, or many of its [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/stockpile)? **Bank**, **accumulate**, **reserve**, **backlog**?

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest *overloading*!  I hope your junior doesn't get stressed. Another term, from computer science (or supermarkets) is *stacking*

Comment: You put the tasks in their (figurative) [**in tray**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/in_tray). If you keep that full you can be sure to demoralise them.

Comment: It sounds like you're *delegating* the work to others.

Comment: I actually really do like that use of "stacking". And no I am not being a mean ol' task-master. I train electricians daily and they often blaze through the training tasks I have assigned for them with very little effort so it's good for me to have a surplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about **task list** or **to-do list**? Yes, they're two words, but they are "concise phrases" that capture what you're seeking. M-W defines **to-do list** as "a list of things to do." A **task list** is the same thing.

Your example:

> I am stacking up things to do, i.e., creating a **task list** or **to-do list**, for one of my juniors at work, so that they will have plenty to do and not run out of work.

Comment: the stacking usage is the most expressive in a way that communicates what I want. I'll probably go with "task-stacking" or something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about **delegating**, as in "delegating some tasks to them"?

M-W defines "delegate" as "to entrust to another," which is what you're ultimately doing with the tasks you're building up.